# Show that the angle bisectors of angles A, B, C of triangle ABC are the altitudes of triangle DEF.

Tags: geometry

Triangle ABC is inscribed in a circle $C(O, r )$. The angle bisectors of A, B, and C intersect the circle in D, E, and F
respectively. Show that the angle bisectors of angles A, B, C of $triangle ABC$ are the altitudes of triangle $DEF$.

[image]

Comment: Do you understand why the $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ in $AGE$ are the same angles as the angles labelled so? Do you see why $2\alpha+2\beta+2\gamma=180^\circ$?

Comment: No I'm not to sure why sorry.

Answer (score 2):

**Using the [Angle of Intersecting Chords Theorem](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/angle-of-intersecting-chords-theorem)**

Using the [Inscribed Angle Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle), $\overset{\large\frown}{AF}=2\gamma$ and $\overset{\large\frown}{AE}=2\beta$; therefore, $\overset{\large\frown}{EF}=2\beta+2\gamma$. Furthermore, $\overset{\large\frown}{DB}=2\alpha$. Since they are the angles of $\triangle ABC$, $2\alpha+2\beta+2\gamma=\pi$. Therefore, using the Angle of Intersecting Chords Theorem, we get that the angle between $\overline{FD}$ and $\overline{EB}$ is
$$
\begin{align}
\frac12\left(\overset{\large\frown}{EF}+\overset{\large\frown}{DB}\right)
&=\frac12\left(2\beta+2\gamma+2\alpha\right)\\[6pt]
&=\frac\pi2
\end{align}
$$
The other intersections are similar.

---

**Proof of the Angle of Intersecting Chords Theorem**

[image]

Using the Inscribed Angle Theorem, $\overset{\large\frown}{AB}=2\angle ACB$ and $\overset{\large\frown}{CD}=2\angle CAD$. The [Exterior Angle Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_angle_theorem) then says that $\angle AOB=\angle ACB+\angle CAD$.

Therefore, we get the Angle of Intersecting Chords Theorem:
$$
2\angle AOB=\overset{\large\frown}{AB}+\overset{\large\frown}{CD}
$$

Answer (score 0):

All triangles drawn from a chord will have the same angle where they touch the circumference.

For instance triangles $\triangle AEF$ and $\triangle ACF$ make the angle $\gamma$ at points $E$ and $C$, respectively.
For the same reason
$\angle EAC = \angle EBC = \beta$.

In $\triangle ABC$, the sum of all angles must be $180^{\circ}$. Thus $2(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)=180^{\circ}$ implying $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=90^{\circ}$. Now if you look at the right triangle $\triangle EGA$, $\angle EGA=180^{\circ}-(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)=90^{\circ}$. Thus, $DG \perp EF$.

Similarly, if the intersection points of lines $ED$ and $CF$ are named $M$ and that of $EB$ and $DF$ are named $N$, the result can be proved for the other two bisecting lines by considering the traingles $\triangle EMC$ and $\triangle BDN$.

Answer (score 0):

In $\triangle DGF$, angles subtended by a common chord in a circle are equal, you will get $\angle DFC=\alpha$ and $\angle CFE=\beta$ and summing them $\angle F=\alpha +\beta$.
Now $\angle ADF=\gamma$ for same reason.
$\Rightarrow$ $180^\circ - (\angle GDF+\angle DFG)=\angle DGF$
$\Rightarrow$ $180^\circ -(\alpha +\beta +\gamma)=\angle DGF=90^\circ$
Similarly all angle bisectors will be perpendiculars for $\triangle DEF$

Answer (score 0):

Let $I$ be the incenter of $ABC$. It is well know'n that $D$ is a center of circle through $BCI$. The same is valid for $E$ and circle $ACI$. So $CI$ is radical line for circles $BCI$ and $ACI$ so $CI$ is perpendicular to line between their centers i.e. $DE$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ 2 \alpha + 2 \beta + 2 \gamma = 2 \pi \rightarrow  \alpha + \beta +  \gamma =  \pi $$
Consider $\Delta EAG \, $

$$\angle HGA + \alpha + \beta +  \gamma = 2 \pi \rightarrow\,  \angle HGA  = \pi$$

$$ \angle \, bisector \, AGD  \, is \perp^{r} to \, line \,EGF... $$

So also for altitudes $ EF,BE$ making unlabeled point of congruence incenter of $\Delta ABC$ the same as orthocenter of $ \Delta DEF$.

Answer (score 0):

(Name the intersection of AB and EF as I)

Join AF

Angle EFA = Beta

Angle BAF = Gamma

By exterior angle property,

Angle GHA = Angle GIA = Beta + Gamma

Angle HAG = Angle IAG = Alpha

From these we can say that Angle AGH = Angle AGI

Also Angle AGH + Angle AGI = 180

Thus, AD is altitude of ∆DEF

Similarly you can show others

(Sorry for not writing symbols)